# How to convert a string-type position to a Coord-type position?

Tags: c++, veins

In my work a txt file is read, among the data in it, there are geographical positions of the vehicles. Due to a problem I am having at the time of reading this file, I want to read this information as the string type, but I need to store the position information as the Coord type. Is it possible to convert a string to Coord?

**Error:**

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('__istream_type' (aka 'basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >') and 'veins::Coord')
```

The error is shown when "while ()" reads the "position" variable as type Coord. The way I thought it would be easier would be to get the position as a string and then convert it to the Coord type and store it in chData.position.

**Code of the method used:**

```
std::ifstream file;
    file.open("chFile.txt");

    if(file.is_open()) {

        int sector;
        int ch;
        Coord position;

        while (file >> sector >> ch >> position) {

            chTableStruct chData;
            chData.ch = ch;
            chData.position = position;

            chTable.insert(std::pair<int,chTableStruct>(sector,chData));

        }
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "The file chFile.txt cannot be opened! it exists?" << endl;
    }
```

**chFile.txt file:**

```
2 20 (401.467,223.4,0)
3 52 (201.446,223.4,0)
1 31 (201.461,623.4,0)
```

Comment: What's the format of your data? Show a part of your input.

Comment: New information was added.

Comment: Seems like you would need ‘Coord’ constructor that accepts string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, sorry my poor English...

When I need to read a string and convert to Coord, in VEINS + OMNeT simulator I do this:

```
Coord MyClass::strToCoord(std::string coordStr){
    //this 2 lines is will remove () if necessary
    coordStr.erase(remove(coordStr.begin(), coordStr.end(), '('), coordStr.end()); //remove '(' from string
    coordStr.erase(remove(coordStr.begin(), coordStr.end(), ')'), coordStr.end()); //remove ')' from string

    char coordCh[30]; //30 or a sufficiently large number
    strcpy(coordCh,coordStr.c_str());
    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    char *token = strtok(coordCh, ",");
    x = stold(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    y = stold(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    z = stold(token);

    cout << "x= " << x << ", y= " << y << ", z= " << z << endl; //comment this line to disable debugging

    return Coord(x,y,z);
}
```

But I don't know if there is already a method implemented in VEINS to do this.

I hope I helped you.